# Install PHP tidy extension into XAMPP in OSX

Tags: php, macos, xampp, tidy

I tired to find out the solution by googling, but there is only a little information no similar posts.

I installed XAMPP 1.8.3 in OSX and I am trying to install tidy extension for php.

However, from the result of researching, there are only some teaching how to install the extension to OSX but not XAMPP, or maybe I misunderstood the whole thing.....

Yet, I am not familiar with the command line,

can you tell me how can I install the extension to XAMPP (the command line??) or some sites that I can refer to??

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

In general: you have two options. Command line tidy (which is easy to install with Homebrew) and the PHP Extension. You can test for both (for example from PHP) like this:

1) Tidy

```
$command = "tidy -version";
exec($command, $return, $code);
if (count($return) > 0) {
    echo "Tidy available!";
}
```

2) PHP Tidy

```
if (extension_loaded("tidy")) {
    echo "PHP Tidy loaded!";
}
```

Since the first approach always has worked for me smoothly I never tried the PHP extension.

So you will need the Terminal!

- Install Homebrew. (as described on http://brew.sh/)
- Run 'brew install tidy'
- Done.

An example (where tidy-in.xml is ugly file and tidy-out.xml the prettified version). Optionally you can provide a config.xml with all kinds of tidy options.

```
$command = "tidy -indent -utf8 -xml -wrap 1000 tidy-in.xml > tidy-out.xml";
exec($command, $return, $code);
if ($code != 0) {
    throw new Exception(printf("Bugger! Something went wrong: %s (%s)", join('<br />', $return), $code));
}
```

Comment: Why would we suggest he uses home brew to install php when he's using xampp?

Comment: @chadpeppers I did not suggest to install php via brew but tidy. That said you're observation is absolutely correct: one should either add or enable php-tidy library and not install the tidy executable.
On the other hand, on systems where you either can't install php extensions or modify the php configuration, the check I outlined above might help someone. So in cases where the PHP extension is missing, but the command line binary exists, one can still use Tidy.
But bottom-line you're right, the php extension should be the preferred one.